# Calculate numpy.std of each pandas.DataFrame's column?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I want to get the `numpy.std` of each column of my `pandas.DataFrame`.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

prices = pd.DataFrame([[-0.33333333, -0.25343423, -0.1666666667],
                       [+0.23432323, +0.14285714, -0.0769230769],
                       [+0.42857143, +0.07692308, +0.1818181818]])

print(pd.DataFrame(prices.std(axis=0)))
```

Here is my code's output:

```
pd.DataFrame([[ 0.39590933],
              [ 0.21234018],
              [ 0.1809432 ]])
```

And here is the right output (if calculate with `np.std`)

```
pd.DataFrame([[ 0.32325862],
              [ 0.17337503],
              [ 0.1477395 ]])
```

**Why am I having such difference?
How can I fix that?**

***NOTE***: I have tried to do this way:

```
print(np.std(prices, axis=0))
```

But I had the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\*****\Documents\******\******\****.py", line 10, in <module>
    print(np.std(prices, axis=0))
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 2812, in std
    return std(axis=axis, dtype=dtype, out=out, ddof=ddof)
TypeError: std() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dtype'
```

Thank you!

Comment: For what it's worth, `print(np.std(prices, axis=0))` doesn't raise an exception anymore (python 3.6.4, numpy 1.14.2, pandas 0.22.0).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Different result for std between pandas and numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46083461/different-result-for-std-between-pandas-and-numpy)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They're both right: they just differ on what the default delta degrees of freedom is.  [`np.std`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.std.html) uses 0, and [`DataFrame.std`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.std.html) uses 1:

```
>>> prices.std(axis=0, ddof=0)
0    0.323259
1    0.173375
2    0.147740
dtype: float64
>>> prices.std(axis=0, ddof=1)
0    0.395909
1    0.212340
2    0.180943
dtype: float64
>>> np.std(prices.values, axis=0, ddof=0)
array([ 0.32325862,  0.17337503,  0.1477395 ])
>>> np.std(prices.values, axis=0, ddof=1)
array([ 0.39590933,  0.21234018,  0.1809432 ])
```

Comment: any thoughts why pandas might have chosen to default with 1 rather than 0?

Comment: @AndyHayden: shouldn't that question be aimed in your devlike direction, not in my userlike one? :^)  Both conventions are common enough across libraries that you always have to check anyway.  In R, for example, `sd(x)` gives the `ddof=1` result.

Comment: haha! Interesting, I suspect that is actually the reason (maybe Wes agreed with R's decision to use ddof=1)!