# Different result for std between pandas and numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, mean

I am trying to subtract every element in the column from its mean and divide by the standard deviation. I did it in two different ways (`numeric_data1` and `numeric_data2`):

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("https://s3.amazonaws.com/demo-datasets/wine.csv")
numeric_data = data.drop("color", 1)
numeric_data1 = ((numeric_data - numeric_data.mean()) /
                 numeric_data.std())
numeric_data2 = ((numeric_data - np.mean(numeric_data, axis=0)) /
                 np.std(numeric_data, axis=0))

type(numeric_data1)  # -> pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
type(numeric_data2)  # -> pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

Both are pandas dataframes and they should have the same result. However, I get different results:

```
numeric_data2 == numeric_data1  # -> False
```

I think the problem stems from how numpy and pandas handle numeric precision:

```
numeric_data.mean() == np.mean(numeric_data, axis=0)      # -> True
numeric_data.std(axis=0) == np.std(numeric_data, axis=0)  # -> False
```

For mean numpy and pandas gave me the same thing, but for standard deviation, I got little different results.

Is my assessment correct or am I making some blunder?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate numpy.std of each pandas.DataFrame's column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20432278/calculate-numpy-std-of-each-pandas-dataframes-column)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When calculating the standard deviation it matters whether you are estimating the standard deviation of an entire population with a smaller sample of that population or are you calculating the standard deviation of the entire population.

If it is a smaller sample of a larger population, you need what is called the *sample standard deviation*.  As it turns out, when you divide the sum of squared differences from the mean by the number of observations, you end up with a biased estimator.  We correct for that by dividing by one less than the number of observations.  We control for this with the argument `ddof=1` for sample standard deviation or `ddof=0` for population standard deviation.

Truth is, it doesn't matter much if your sample size is large.  But you will see small differences.

Use the degrees of freedom argument in your [`pandas.DataFrame.std`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.std.html) call:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("https://s3.amazonaws.com/demo-datasets/wine.csv")
numeric_data = data.drop("color", 1)
numeric_data1 = ((numeric_data - numeric_data.mean()) /
                 numeric_data.std(ddof=0))  # <<<
numeric_data2 = ((numeric_data - np.mean(numeric_data, axis=0)) /
                 np.std(numeric_data, axis=0))

np.isclose(numeric_data1, numeric_data2).all()  # -> True
```

Or in the [`np.std`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.std.html) call:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("https://s3.amazonaws.com/demo-datasets/wine.csv")
numeric_data = data.drop("color", 1)
numeric_data1 = ((numeric_data - numeric_data.mean()) /
                 numeric_data.std())
numeric_data2 = ((numeric_data - np.mean(numeric_data, axis=0)) /
                 np.std(numeric_data, axis=0, ddof=1))  # <<<

np.isclose(numeric_data1, numeric_data2).all()  # -> True
```

Comment: Could you please explain it more?

Comment: Look at the docs for [numpy.std](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.std.html) see the ddof default = zero, and [pandas.DataFrame.std](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.std.html) see ddof default = one.

Comment: Thanks @ScottBoston it makes sense. I had no idea about ddof

Comment: There you go, more explanation.