# Why pandas does not give the same std deviation as numpy?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to calulate standard deviation for numbers from 1 to 7

I get different results for numpy and for pandas. I am sure that the result should be 2:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'vals': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]})
>>> df["vals"].std()
2.160246899469287
>>> df["vals"].mean()
4.0

>>>np.std([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
2.0
>>>np.mean([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
4.0
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: (cannot reproduce)

Comment: do: `np.std(df['vals'], ddof=1)` you get the same answer.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20432278/calculate-numpy-std-of-each-pandas-dataframes-column) is my dup for numpy vs pandas std, but I have trouble believing `df["vals"].mean()` gave 2.